# opening the pry console in sandbox mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pry

I recently found pry and I find it to be a great replacement for irb. I figured I'd use it as replacement for my ROR development and debugging. 
I know that to open pry with a rails app you simply type

```
pry -r ./config/environment
```

My question is that is there a way to open the pry console in a sandbox mode so that any modification I make does not affect my database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly add "pry-rails" gem into Gemfile

```
gem 'pry-rails', :group => :development
```

Then `bundle install`

Then launch rails console in sandbox mode

```
# in development env
$ rails c --sandbox
# or in test env
$ rails c test --sandbox
```

That's all. Pry will replace irb automatially. Enjoy!

Ref: https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Setting-up-Rails-or-Heroku-to-use-Pry#

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to modify your Gemfile, you can do this once you open pry:

```
require 'active_record/railties/console_sandbox'
```

I have this defined in a method in my `~/.pryrc` so it's easy to use.